# Unexpected behavior of pthread (in cygwin)

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, cygwin

I wrote the following simple code:

```
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void* printThreadFunction()
{
    puts("***got here*****");   
}


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
     pthread_t printThread;
     if (pthread_create(&printThread, NULL, printThreadFunction, NULL) != 0) {
             perror("pthread_create");
             exit(1);
     }
     pthread_join(printThread, NULL);
}
```

This code prints `***got here*****` as I expect. However, if I change `printThreadFunction()` to be:

```
void* printThreadFunction()
{
        puts("***got here*****");
        while(1); // change here       
}
```

So the code enters an infinite loop, but no printing is being done to the screen- why is that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is stdout line buffered, unbuffered or indeterminate by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723795/is-stdout-line-buffered-unbuffered-or-indeterminate-by-default)

Comment: @Marian As you say `stdout` is line-buffered by default. But [`puts`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/puts) *do* write a trailing newline, so explicit flushing should not be needed.

Comment: To the OP: You do not redirect the output of the program to a file (using something similar to `./a.out > some_file` when running)?

Comment: try `fflush(stdout);` after puts.

Comment: Possibly related: [Cygwin terminal buffers STDOUT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37706946/2402272)